# Java recursive difference in array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, iteration, divide-and-conquer

I'm currently learning Java and I stumbled on an exercise I can't finish.

The task is to write a recursive method that takes an array and returns the difference of the greatest and smallest value.

For example `{12, 5, 3, 8}` should return `5` (`8 - 3`). It is important to note that it is only allowed to compare values in their right order (`result = rightValue - leftValue`). For example `12-3 = 9` would not be allowed. Think of it like stock values. You want to find out which time to buy and sell the stocks to make the largest profit.

It was quiet easy to implement this iterative but I have no idea how to do it recursive. Also it is part of the task to solve it by using divide and conquer.

Comment: show us what you've tried so far

Comment: @Turing85 No it is only allowed to compare values in their right order. Think of it like stock values. You want to find out which time to buy and sell the stocks to make the largest profit.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. + Your example does not make sense to me.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I was thinking of splitting the array in halves and comparing the values after that but I don´t really know what values to return.

Comment: @Nbert you have certain combinations of values you have to check (last with second-tolast, last with third to last,...., second-to-last with third-to-last,.... , thrid with second, third with first, second with first). This can be done recursively. You return the maximum value found in this way or some object of a self-written class, containing all necessary information. This is of course just one of many possible solutions, but maybe it gets you started.

Comment: I down voted the question based on the author's own admittance that "I have to admit that I didn´t made a good job explaining what my problem is. This task is meant to simulate a stock market. You try to maximize your profit by buying at the lowest value and selling at the highest." Please revise your question & this also sounds like a homework or assignment.

Comment: @AryanNaim Yes it is a task like I said in the first sentence of my question. The task doesn't mention a stock market this was my idea to visualize the example. I edited my question since you seemed to get it wrong. Nevertheless you can down vote the question if you want to. I am very grateful for every answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used divide and conquer approach here. I believe the trick here is to include middle in both the arrays that we're splitting the main array into.

/* edge cases ignored here */

```
int findMax(int[] arr, int left, int right){

if(right-left == 1) return (arr[right]-arr[left]);

int middle = left + (right-left)/2;

int max1 = findMax(arr, left, middle);
int max2 = findMax(arr, middle, right);

if(max1 >= 0 && max2 >= 0) return max1+max2;

else return Math.max(max1,max2);

}
```

Comment: That solved my question, thank you very much!

Comment: Could you explain why the middle has to be  `left + (right-left)/2` ? I expected it to be only `(right-left)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think recursion is very effective on this. You would probably never do this(other than homework). Something like this would do it:

```
int findGreatestDifference(Vector<Integer> numbers, int greaterDifference){
    if(numbers.size() == 1 ) //return at last element
        return greaterDifference;
    int newDifference = (numbers.get(0) - numbers.get(1));
    if (newDifference > greaterDifference)
        greaterDifference = newDifference;

    numbers.remove(numbers.size() - 1);
    findGreatestDifference(numbers, greaterDifference);
    return greaterDifference;
}
```

first time you call it, pass 0 as the greater difference, and again I don't find this as an effective way to do it. Iteration would be way better for this.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know recursion is stupid for this exercise but one part of it was doing it iterative and the other is doing it with recursion. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -3):

Algorithm (this is pretty much a sort task , then the subtraction step is trivial)

1) First sort the arrays (use recursive merge sort for large arrays and recursive insertion for smaller arrays).

Merge sort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Insertion sort (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

2) Use the arrays smallest index[0] to get the smallest value & index[array.length-1] to get the largest

3)compute the difference (dont know what you mean by right order?)

Comment: This will result 12 - 3 = 9, which OP clearly said is not the answer.

Comment: If you sort the array then you don´t have to worry about the order. I was specifically asked to implement an divide and conquer algorithm.

Comment: I have to admit that I didn´t made a good job explaining what my problem is.  This task is meant to simulate a stock market. You try to maximize your profit by buying at the lowest value and selling at the highest.

Comment: if your trying to simulate a stock market , then your approach is probably the worst approach, since stock data is streaming time series. Determining whether a price is the lowest OR highest will be based on historical modelling, and the analysis window is also important. Lowest OR highest price in the last 1 sec, 1 minute, 1 day, 1 week, its relative. Further I based my explanation on your question which you admitted was not phrased well.